# error con grid-template-columns

Tags: css

Cuando coloco en css esta linea de codigo me marca error en GRID y el GRID-TEMPLATE-COLUMNS, me dice que no es soportado por internet explorer, me da dos soluciones pero tampoco funciona que es `-ms-display: grid;` (esta parte si funciona) y la otra `-ms-grid-column: 1fr 1fr;` y esto no funciona, he probado de varia maneras y no funciona. Lo marca en rojo Visual Studio y no guarda los cambios. Que puedo hacer?

```
.diseño {
    display: grid;    
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
}

.diseño {
    display: grid;    
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Buen día, el parámetro es `-ms-grid-columns` te hace falta una "s" tu pusiste `-ms-grid-column`

Comment: Aún con s me sigue marcando el error en grid-template-columns q no es soportado x explorer

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, no agregues caracteres especiales (acentos, ñ, etc) a código JS o CSS, primero porque un navegador que no soporte esos caracteres hará que tu estilo se rompa y segundo porque es una mala práctica.

Ahora, ni `-ms-display` ni `-ms-grid-colum` son correctos, primero porque la propiedad `display` es una propiedad universal, el sufijo cambia en el valor de esta y luego porque `-ms-grid-columns` no funciona como funcionaría hoy en día un `grid-template-columns`.

Por último, no sé por qué quieres agregar soporte para IE, hoy en día ya se ha eliminado por completo y nadie (o casi nadie) lo usa, Microsoft le quitó el soporte e incluso Windows 7 ya viene con Edge (el nuevo navegador basado en WebKit), todos los navegadores son modernos y ya no te tienes que estar preocupando por el soporte para IE, ya que, no es necesario.

```css
.grid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 100px minmax(200px, 500px) 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 100px minmax(200px, 500px) 1fr;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.small {
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.minmax {
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    grid-column: 2;
}

.fr {
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell small">
        <p>100px</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell minmax">
        <p>minmax(200px, 500px)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell fr">
        <p>1fr</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ante todo muchas gracias por tu respuesta y no no quiero agregar soporte a IE lo que pasa q al escribir el codigo VS me marca el error que falta eso y no me deja guardar cambios ni seguir adelante con el formulario

Comment: @sergiomerlo Si te marca algún error relacionado a `Unexpected character` es por la ñ o caracteres especiales como te dije, pero dudo mucho que no te deje guardarlo a menos que tengas una extensión que te obligue a poner los prefijos para un _Cross-Browser compatibility_, de todas maneras, puedes indicarme por acá el error que te marca.

Comment: ESE ES EL ERROR QUE ME MARCA EN GRID-TEMPLATE COLUMNS YSIMILAR EN GRID   *****  specifies, as a space-separated track list, the line names and track sizing functions of the grid.

Syntax: none | <track-list> | <auto-track-list> | subgrid <line-name-list>?

MDN Reference

'grid-template-columns' is not supported by Internet Explorer. Add '-ms-grid-columns' to support Internet Explorer 10+